# Understanding Tensors

Tags: physics, matrix

I don't seem to be able to visualize tensors. I am reading The Morgan Kauffman Game Physics Engine Development and he uses tensors to represent aerodynamics but he doesn't explain them so I am not really able to visualize them.

Comment: You'd be better off at http://math.stackexchange.com/, I believe.

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but physics and math forums do not help at all they explain it in a very complex way. I just need to understand the basics.

Comment: Guys at MSE are pretty cool, and on PSE, I ask them questions all the time and they answer pretty great. Just state that you need a really simple explanation and maybe tell them the level of your education, you're bound to get a great answer.

Comment: MSE and PSE are great for more specific clarifications, but few of the guys there manage to provide an useful view for a game programmer. They do give you great theoretical insights, but those answers are very light in terms of valuable information for a game developer with little to no interest in the more abstract aspects of those scientific notions. Usually, all of that complicatedly expressed mathematical formulae are reduced to nothing more than matrix algebra and basic calculus.

Comment: Feynman on answering these kinds of questions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMFPe-DwULM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of commenting, I decided to post this as an answer. Of course, it is a subjective view, but for students trying to understand the language of game physics and maths, it's a gem. You can view the explanation here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5liqUk0ZTw

Comment: very good video.